# Game with "pure" Nash equilibrium but not SPNE

Tags: game-theory, economics, algorithmic-game-theory

after trying to find the answer for this problem for the last few days and crawling through loads of papers and notes, I decided to ask in case someone else has a good example for me.

I am trying to give a specific example of a extensive form game in which there is a pure Nash Equilibrium but no Subgame-perfect Nash equilibrium. Following from Kuhn (1953) I know that it has to be a game of imperfect information.

Does anyone have a good example for me on what such a game would look like?

I went through the threads here and checked if there was such a question, but couldn't find one. Another thread suggested Matching pennies in extensive form but that only has a Nash equilibrium in mixed strategies. But I am looking for an example with pure strategies.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a very nice discussion about nonexistence of SPE in continuous games of almost perfect information in Section 2 of: Harris, Reny and  Robson, "The Existence of Subgame-Perfect Equilibrium in Continuous Games with Almost Perfect Information: A Case for Public Randomization", *Econometrica*, Vol. 63, No. 3 (May, 1995), pp. 507-544

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Provided a good starting point to go further!

Comment: Let us know if you can make progress.